# Redirect to another page without loading current page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect to another page from 1 page without showing contents of that page using javascript/jquery.

So for example I would be either typing or coming from a search engine to a page on my website say `www.mysite.com/aaa/` and I should get redirected to `www.mysite.com/bbb/` without showing the contents of `www.mysite.com/aaa/`.

The server side is asp.net and I can do this using `Response.Redirect` but I do not want a code change.

From my limited knowledge, I cannot use `document.ready` or `window.load` as both will load the contents of the page in the browser before redirecting.

I am not aware of any other thing which would help me achieve this. Tried hard searching but could not get anything useful.

I got something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221452/how-to-redirect-to-another-jsp-page-without-loading-the-current-page). I can have this in the header but right at the top of the header might not be possible. Plus the answer is not looking very convincing. However, can try it out and update this question with the findings.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't really stop this client-side. The response will be generated on the server and sent to the client before any JS code is run. This means that HTML will be shown before any redirect via `window.location` is performed in JavaScript. If you want this behaviour you have no other choice than to do it server side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the the web browser engine reads an HTML document and identifies a `script` element, it immediately invokes the JavaScript interpretator and executes the code. So, if your document starts with a JavaScript which redirects away from the page, the client shouldn't be shown the remaining document. Something like this could work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //using "replace" removes the current page from browser history
        location.replace('page_b.html');
    </script>
```

Also, if there is something on the current page that should not be displayed to the client while the redirect is in process - you can inject some additional CSS, like

```
<style type='text/css'>
   body {display:none}
</style>
```

Comment: very nicely explained! Tried this out and it seems to work. Need some testing but it should be very much acceptable to the tester and client. Thanks!