# Hide body if browser is IE 7 and lower

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For all users coming to a website with IE 7 and lower I like to display a message and **only** this message while not displaying the `body` or any other part of the website.

Having this code in the `head`

```
<head>
    <!-- Target IE 7 EQUAL and LOWER (7, 6, 5, ..) -->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>        
        <div id="ie7lower">
            <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">
                <p>Click here to update your browser..</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">body {display:none;}</style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
...
```

I assume that the div id `ie7lower` should be shown as this is still in the `head` and with the inline style I tell the `body` to not display.

However as soon as I use the inline style the div id `ie7lower` is also hidden.

Could it be that IE 7 and lower put the `head` inside the `body` or assume that the `head` is part of the `body` and therefore the div id `ie7lower` is also not shown any more?

Basically I want to hide or even better not even load the entire website for users with IE 7 and lower and simply display them the message to update their browser. Would be great if this can be done without JavaScript.

**EDIT**
While hiding the page content with the wrapper not being displayed and this being a solution to what I wanted to do this also did indeed load all the other scripts and CSS in the conditional comments.

Trying to reduce HTTP requests as much as possible and quickly leading IE 7 and lower users to the "update your browser" message/page I used [Redirect to another page without loading current page in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252945/redirect-to-another-page-without-loading-current-page-in-jquery) to redirect them to a bare minimal page on the same domain while not loading all the extra scripts and CSS I have in place for IE 8 and IE 9.

```
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252945/redirect-to-another-page-without-loading-current-page-in-jquery -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        location.replace('ie/outdated.html');
    </script>            
<![endif]-->
```

Be careful here with not having **`/`** in front of `ie/outdated.html` if your `outdated.html` is on the same domain!

If anyone is interested this is a starting point for an "outdated IE" message/page.

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">       
        <title>Company Name | maximum 64 characters long title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Site description | maximum 130 chars long description for search engine snippet">
        <!-- http://blog.powermapper.com/blog/post/Page-Title-Length-for-Search-Engines.aspx -->                    
    </head>     
    <body>
        <div id="outdated_container" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
            <h1>You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser that does not support this website's features.</h1>
            <h1><a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Please upgrade your browser</a> to improve your web experience.</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using this approach I merely get

```
"GET /Domain/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7866
"GET /Domain/ie/outdated.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1017
```

instead of all the other HTTP requests the normal website has for all browsers as well as IE 8 and IE 9.

This though means that JS has to be enabled in IE 7 and lower by default. Given this is by now most possibly a tiny fraction of users (surfing the web with IE 7 and JS disabled) I can live with this approach.

Comment: Do you really still have enough IE6 / IE7 users to justify even bothering to tell them to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not place content that is supposed to be rendered to the user inside the HTML head.

I would recommend wrapping everything in a wrapper that gets hidden when the browser is IE7 or lower.

```html
<head>
  <!--[if lte IE 7]>        
    <style type="text/css">#wrapper {display:none;}</style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>        
  <div id="ie7lower">
    <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">
      <p>Click here to update your browser..</p>
    </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->

<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it bad practice or otherwise not recommended to place content in the html head? I am trying to reduce load for IE 7 and lower as much as possible and thought I can "cut off" everything after the head like this. Do you actually know why my approach does not work?

Comment: The HTML <head> tag is for metadata related to document, like title, charset, links to CSS/JS, page description etc. It is not meant for content. Maybe browser will display content in head but this bad practice and invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

Using some sort of browser detection in your head is fine.

But putting content that should be visible to users is not.

You need the part visible to users within the body.

update per your comments:

Not sure what you are referring to but i will address both.

1. your div does not show in the head section because it simply is not meant to be a visible section.
2. If it is still not showing while in the body you have another issue. your if statement is probably not uncommenting it. You can check this is a browser using their debugging tools to view whats going on.

If you installed anything for browser detection make sure it is all installed right.

Comment: Is it bad practice or otherwise not recommended to place content in the html `head` for let's say IE 7 and lower? Is there a link or docs or something else explaining to me why the `ie7lower` div also does not get displayed?

Comment: @lowtechsun it's more of a "never ever" type of thing to put html content in the head. However you could link to a JS file in the head that could alter the page for you in one swift move. ||| Regarding your next point can you clarify? Like, why does it the div not show when in the head or....?

Comment: Yes, I meant when not displaying the `body` I thought IE would at least display the `head` and inside the `head` read the CSS rule and hide the `body` afterwards while still showing the `ie7lower` div. Another thing that came to mind is I could redirect to a `domain/ie7` page on the website if it is IE 7 and lower and there only show the message. Like this I can also minimize the http requests since I have jQuery, respondJS, remJS, html5shiv and media.matchJS for IE 8 and 9 respectively. Good approach?

Comment: @lowtechsun You would need something in the head to place your div inside the body. This can be done with JS. But under no circumstances should a browser show what is in your head. (without looking at the page source). That would be a mighty big security issue if it did.

Comment: OK, got your edit, the `ie7lower` div does not show in the `head` section since that is not visible in **any** browser, not just IE. To your 2nd point, no not using any browser sniffing tools and the if statement is properly commented like in my question's code. What do you think about the redirect to an IE 7 page and there only show the message while **not** loading any of the extra JS that I use to support IE 8 and 9?

Comment: I guess my last comment's 2nd part will be another question. Thank you both for your help. ==> Edit This comes close to what I am looking for I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252945/redirect-to-another-page-without-loading-current-page-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

use this code to hide body...

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>  
<style>
    body {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```